# RabbitMQ DLX does not work when publishing directly to a queue

Tags: rabbitmq, dead-letter

I have encountered an issue, and I can't find any solutions for it either.

I have 2 RMQ servers, let's call them RMQ1 and RMQ2. A Message is first published to `main_exchange` on RMQ1 which routes it to `main_queue` on RMQ1. There are no consumers set up on RMQ1.
Queues in RMQ2 are **federated queues** of RMQ1 and consumers work on RMQ2 queues.
I also have `retry_queue` and `retry_exchange` on both servers, and DLX for `main_queue` is set to `retry_exchange`.

The problem is that when I reject or NAck a message on RMQ2 (federated queues) the message is dropped from the queue and DLX is not triggered so the message completely vanishes, but when I publish messages to the `main_exchange` in RMQ2, DLX works perfectly fine.

DLX does not again work when I publish messages directly to queues (instead of publishing to an exchange) on RMQ1 or RMQ2 
This problem again does not stand when I federate exchanges, but in this way, I have exactly the same messages twice on both servers and queues.

My workaround until now has been to use shovel from `main_queue` on RMQ1 to `main_exchange` on RMQ2.
My question is why DLX does not work when using federation queues which is the solution for me.